# How to get vale of property of key in parent's generic type?

Tags: typescript

Trying to explain this is a bit hard, so I'll just show the code:

```js
type FormFields = {
  email: string;
  count: number;
};

type FieldMap<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = Record<
  keyof T,
  FieldMapping<T>
>;

interface FieldMapping<Values extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  label: string;
  initialValue: Values[keyof Values];
}

const formDetails: FieldMap<FormFields> = {
  email: {
    label: "Email",
    initialValue: "", // should enforce string here
  },
  count: {
    label: "Count",
    initialValue: "test", // string should not be allowed here - should enforce number
  },
};
```

Is there any way to get the `initialValue` parameter to enforce the typings from the `FormFields` based on the key? I know the `initialValue: Values[keyof Values]` is the issue - but I don't know what the solution is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out, didn't know you could use the `key` as a type in typescript. I changed the FieldMap to the following and and changed the FieldMapping generic:

```js
export type FieldMap<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [key in StringKeys<T>]: FieldMapping<T[key]>;
};

interface FieldMapping<T extends unknown> {
  label: string;
  initialValue: T;
}
```